# How to find Position X & Y (image, area)

Tags: macos, html, css, sprite

I am currently in the process of creating sprites for images. How can you find the X & Y position on an image.

Is there a program that does that?(MAC) because i require it for creating area tag.

Thanks again for your help

e.g. background:url('img_navsprites.gif') -47px 0;

How can i get the -47px by 0 through a program of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like that?

[SpritePad](http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/)